# Can't get whitespace added to string in PHP

Tags: php, string, whitespace

I"m trying to make a web form that outputs to flat text file line by line what the input to the web form is.  Several of the fields are not required but the output file must input blank spaces in for whatever is not filled out.  Here is what I'm trying:

```
$output = $_SESSION["emp_id"];
if(!empty($_POST['trans_date'])) {
    $output .= $_POST["trans_date"];
}else{
$output = str_pad($output, 6);
}
if(!empty($_POST['chart'])) {
    $output .= $_POST["chart"];
}else{
    $output = str_pad($output, 6);
}

write_line($output);

function write_line($line){
        $file = 'coh.txt';
        // Open the file to get existing content
        $current = file_get_contents($file);
        // Append a new line to the file
        $current .= $line . PHP_EOL;
        // Write the contents back to the file
        file_put_contents($file, $current);
    }
```

However, when I check my output the spaces don't show up.  Any ideas on what's going on with this?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: If those are text fields then they will be set, just empty.  Check for `empty()`.

Comment: that made no difference

Comment: `$output .= $_POST["trans_date"] . " ";` and `$output = $_POST["chart"] . " ";` try that. If you want to add a space after those POSTs.

Comment: abracadaver you were right about it not passing the condition and empty fixed that part but it's still not appending the whitespace in the output

Comment: Fred I think you're misinterpreting what I'm trying to do.  I'm only trying to add the whitespace is the form is not filled out.

Comment: adding .= next to $output solve your problem?

Comment: thanks fortune, i copied my code down wrong here but that's not the problem, I had the .= in my actual code and it's still not working

Comment: This looks like an error, but is probably not your problem: `$output = .str_pad($output, 1, " ");`

Comment: Thanks tecbrat, I should have copied and pasted my code instead of quickly trying to rewrite it here, I've fixed it

Comment: The way I read `str_pad()` [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php), it looks like you should not be concatenating, but only re-assigning the value. `$output = str_pad($output, 1, " ");`

Comment: I believe you are right TecBrat, but I've changed it and it's still doing the same thing.

Comment: did you try : $output .= str_pad($output, 6);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str_pad` is padding with spaces, not adding spaces. You're padding an existing value with spaces so that it is 6 characters long, not adding 6 whitespaces to the value. So if `$_SESSION["emp_id"]` is 6 characters long or more, nothing will be added.

Answer (score 1):

[str_pad()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) won't add that number of spaces, but rather makes the string that length by adding the appropriate number of spaces. Try [str_repeat()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php):

```
$output = $_SESSION["emp_id"];
if(!empty($_POST['trans_date'])) {
    $output .= $_POST["trans_date"];
}else{
    $output = $output . str_repeat(' ', 6);
}
if(!empty($_POST['chart'])) {
    $output .= $_POST["chart"];
}else{
    $output = $output . str_repeat(' ', 6);
}

write_line($output);

function write_line($line) {
    $file = 'coh.txt';
    // Open the file to get existing content
    $current = file_get_contents($file);
    // Append a new line to the file
    $current .= $line . PHP_EOL;
    // Write the contents back to the file
    file_put_contents($file, $current);
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: I'm not trying to get the it to print out as an HTML element.  I'm trying to to create a PHP variable that is exported to a text file.  At no point am I trying to make it HTML.

Comment: str_pad() should work fine for adding whitespace to a file. Where is your $output being written to a file?

Comment: It is indeed already using str_pad() and I've tried it with and without explicitly stating that the " " in the arguments and get the same result, it won't add the spaces (not even 1)

Comment: Not correctly. It shouldn't be concatenated back to itself as str_pad() already returns the string.

Comment: You are correct versalle88, that is how I should be using it.  However, I've changed it to no avail.

Comment: @user3200286 I've updated my answer using str_repeat(). It worked in my test.